# Magento 2 - Get current page type

Tags: magento2, php, page, if, get

I have a title.phtml which loads the page title for the pages in the webshop. What I need to do is detect whether it's a product page or something else...

What is the best way yo do this?

Regards,

Comment: do you got your answer???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are checking for just testing you can try this

```
echo $this->getRequest()->getFullActionName();
```

if you are at

```
Search page it will be  -> catalogsearch_result_index

category page it will be  -> catalog_catagory_view

product page it will be  -> catalog_product_view
```